# Snapping by increment doesn't seem to work in blender 2.8

Tags: snapping

I'm new to blender, but my problem is that when I use the snapping tool, it doesn't always work in blender 2.8, and idk why. Nearly every video is on an older version of blender and says that holding down ctrl works, but I can't find that in any keybinding, or anywhere in 2.8, so I've been trying to use the magnet button, but even that doesn't seem to work when I move objects
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hello :). It works just fine in my 2.8. What *exactly* doesn't work for you?

Comment: when I press ctrl, or when I press the magnet, and then move the item, it doesn't snap by increment, it just moves normally without being accurate

Comment: Okay, perhaps the new Blender 2.83 would work better? :)